# tengo problemas con INNER JOIN SQL SERVER

Tags: sql-server, tsql

Soy nuevo en lo que a base de datos se refiere.. y estoy trabajando con el tema de `INNER JOIN` y la verdad es que no me queda muy claro de como funciona y como aplicarlo.. ya que tengo un ejercicio y no me puedo unir una tercera tabla que esta relacionada.. alguien seria tan amable de explicármelo.. aquí un ejemplo de lo que estoy haciendo.. no se si esta bien o mal.. ya que no me da ningún resultado..

```
select 
  TDetalle_pedido.id_detalle_pedido,
  TProducto.nombre_producto, 
  TDetalle_pedido.cantidad,
  TCliente.nombre_cliente 
from TDetalle_pedido
inner join TProducto on TDetalle_pedido.id_producto = TProducto.id_producto
inner join TPedido on TDetalle_pedido.id_pedido = TPedido.id_pedido 
inner join TCliente on TDetalle_pedido.id_pedido = TCliente.id_cliente 
order by TProducto.nombre_producto;
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Imagino que te aseguraste que las tablas tienes datos. Revisa que efectivamente hayas creado las `FK` que relacionan las tablas entre sí, ya que tu código se ve bien =)

Comment: gracias por tu comentario.. y acabo de verificar que todas mis tablas tienen contenido.. cuando relaciono solo con la tabla producto si me da los resultados que pido.. pero cuando quiero llamar los datos de nombre_cliente de la tabla cliente no me resulta..

Comment: Cambia esta linea `inner join TCliente on TDetalle_pedido.id_pedido = TCliente.id_cliente ` por `inner join TCliente on TPedido.id_cliente = TCliente.id_cliente `

Comment: gracias compañero.. ahora si corren los datos a la perfeccion.. tendre q seguir practicando.. muchas gracias..

Comment: El problema esta en que debes tener muy claro los campos que relacionan tus dos tablas para que te funcione el `inner join`, son cosas que vas perfeccionando mientras practicas tus querys.

Answer (score 3):

El problema parece estar en esta línea:

```
inner join TCliente on TDetalle_pedido.id_pedido = TCliente.id_cliente
```

Estás haciendo join entre `id_pedido` e `id_cliente`, que me imagino es incorrecto.

Siguiendo tu modelo de datos, el join debería ser:

```
select 
  dp.id_detalle_pedido,
  pr.nombre_producto, 
  dp.cantidad,
  cl.nombre_cliente 
from TDetalle_pedido dp
inner join TProducto pr
    on dp.id_producto = pr.id_producto
inner join TPedido pe
    on dp.id_pedido = pe.id_pedido 
inner join TCliente cl
    on pe.id_cliente = cl.id_cliente 
order by p.nombre_producto;
```

Comment: gracias compañero.. ahora si corren los datos a la perfeccion.. tendre q seguir practicando.. muchas gracias por tu tiempo..